# how to Process pixels remaining after image segmentation with opencv

Tags: c++, opencv

I made a code that reads the image, rotates the part, and outputs it into one image.
By the way, my image is an image of 512*512, and pixels that cannot be processed when the size of the pixel segmentation is not a common factor of 512 appear on a gray screen. Can you tell me how to handle this gray screen?
I will attach my code and a link to the output image.
[Output_img Link.  Unprocessable pixels are printed on a gray screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vQZbK.png)

here is my code

```
int div_img_size = 360; //Size of pixels you want to split
int rot = 360; //Angle to rotate
Mat img = imread("Lenna.png");
Mat output;
Mat outputROI;
output.create(512, 512, CV_8UC3);
Mat SplitImage;

for (int i = 0; i < img.cols / n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < img.rows / n; j++)
        {
            SplitImage = rotate(img(Rect(Point(j * n, i * n), Point((j + 1) * n, (i + 1) * n))), rot);
            outputROI = output((Rect(Point(j * n, i * n), Point((j + 1) * n, (i + 1) * n))));
            SplitImage.copyTo(outputROI);
        }
    }
    imshow("result_img", output);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You copied the ROI only.
You have to clone `img` to `output` as an initial value or copy the remaining area manually.

```
Mat img = imread("Lenna.png");
Mat output = image(cv::Rect(0,0,512,512)).clone(); // You should check the bounds!

// do same
```

Comment: @Moondo If the answer was helpful, consider [accepting it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).